# python error while executing post-commit script from console

Tags: python, svn, post-commit, svn-hooks

```
#sh post-commit
```

I am getting bellow error, How to fix this.

sh post-commit

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/SVNData/testrepo/hooks/mailer.py", line 1353, in <module>
sys.argv[3:3+expected_args])
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/svn/core.py", line 281, in run_app
return func(application_pool, *args, **kw)
File "/SVNData/testrepo/hooks/mailer.py", line 81, in main
revision = int(cmd_args[0])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
revision = int(''.join(cmd_args[0].split()))
```

Comment: Got this error  "TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
"

Comment: Now it is same..  revision = int(''.join(cmd_args[0].split()))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''